# how electron can go towards nucleus and then go far apart from it as in p orbital?see discription

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In p orbital shape is dumbbell shaped which means electron go in the shape of dumbbell means first towards nucleus then go away from it. How can be this possible because first electron is attracted towards nucleus now it is very close means attraction force will be more and how it can go away from nucleus?

Answer (score 1):

Dont think of orbitals as an orbit of the electron around the nucleus. Thats a HUGE no no. The orbitals are solutions to the wave function for a specific value of energy that characterizes each shell. This purely means that an orbital captures the area where the probability density of finding an electron is high, not where the electron orbits. So the dummbell shape results from the probability density, not the orvit of the electron.

Comment: Consider the 'orbital' to be the electron - it is not a point particle when localized in an orbital. The whole Bohr model, and the subsequent use of 'orbital' as nomenclature clouds the minds of physics and chemistry students. Welcome to the world of quantum physics - it is not classical mechanics anymore.